# Angular cannot find control with FormGroup when using an array of FormGroups

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

My aim is to create dynamic forms that I allow my users to create. They create a JSON file which describes the form which I then load. These forms can be quite complex (including external links to download key value pairs etc). For the formatting I decided to load the fields from a JSON file from the top down i.e. one field per line. If you want to have more than one field you create an array - these are then aligned horizontally.

I did look at https://github.com/hamzahamidi/ajsf but decided against it as there seems to be a lot of overhead and I could not update the form data on the fly (only when using the data as the form layout).

I started out with this example: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form. I have my code working for the JSON file without the arrays although I did need to change the toFormGroup function to first create the array of Controls BEFORE I added them to the group else I had the dreaded "Cannot find control with path" error. It seems to be a timing / race condition problem as I did not have this when I did not load from the files (i.e. no Promise). Check out the toFormGroup function to see what I did.

I am now trying to load the array... AFAIK I am doing everything correctly but I am getting the error:

ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: '0 -> surname'

I have created a stripped down example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-knft2z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fquestion.service.ts

the error is marked in the code of the constructor is app.component.ts => if I pass the simple json file all is well, if I pass the code with the array I have the array in the dynamicForm variable but get the above error in the console. Just change the parameter here to 'simple' and the code works i.e. fields from top to bottom.

Any help here would be great as I new to angular / reactive forms and have not been able to find my error now for 2 days!

Thanx

Comment: Hey @Ursus Schneider. Here is an Example of dynamic forms. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-builder?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Hi @OwaisAhmedKhan. Thank you for the example - unfortunately it does not solve my problem as you are just using a flat list. That I have working if you look at my example code. My problem is as soon as I do a pass an array of entries to the component I get the error described.